# Using the "click" function to programatically launch R shiny Action Button

Tags: r, shiny

I recently came across the click() function and want to incorporate this in to my app.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/shinyjs/versions/1.1/topics/click

However attempting to run the given example:

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyjs)

  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
      "Count:", textOutput("number", inline = TRUE), br(),
      actionButton("btn", "Click me"), br(),
      "The button will be pressed automatically every 3 seconds"
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$number <- renderText({
        input$btn
      })
      observe({
        click("btn")
        invalidateLater(3000)
      })
    }
  )
}
# }
```

Did not give the desired behaviour.  It appears no auto-clicking is taking place!  Can anybody explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It works for me, did you try to restart your session?

Comment: Yes restarting seems to have done the trick, strange, why would this be happening?

Comment: I guess it is related to a package you loaded before, maybe the function `click()` in package `shinyjs` was masked by a function with the same name in another package