# How to start app in fullscreen with shinyjs and shinyfullscreen

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

I'm trying to figure out a way to use shinyjs::click to simulate a click event and this way make the app fullscreen using shinyfullscreen::fullscreen_all.

The following code demonstrates the use of shinyfullscreen::fullscreen_all. It uses a modalwindow to simulate a landing page, and has a close button that, other than closing the modal, makes the app fullscreen. I also include shinyjs::click to simulate an initial click which should make the app fullscreen when it starts. But it doesn't.

```
library(shiny)
library(bs4Dash)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyfullscreen)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "fullscreen App"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    plotOutput("plot1")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  histdata <- rnorm(1)
  observeEvent(once = TRUE,ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = FALSE, eventExpr = histdata, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Landing Page", 
      p('some content'),
      actionButton("qwert", "Close"),
      shinyjs::click("qwert"),
      fullscreen_all(click_id = "qwert"),
      footer = NULL
    ))
  })

  observeEvent(input$qwert, {removeModal()})
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(rnorm(10))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any solution to this problem?
Thank you.

I also adapted the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329181/using-the-click-function-to-programatically-launch-r-shiny-action-button), which I think illustrates better the problem.

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyjs)
  library(shinyfullscreen)
  
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
      "Count:", textOutput("number", inline = TRUE), br(),
      actionButton("btn", "Click me"), br(),
      fullscreen_all(click_id = "btn"),
      "The button will be pressed automatically every 3 seconds"
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$number <- renderText({
        input$btn
      })
      observe({
        click("btn")
        print("111")
        invalidateLater(3000)
      })
    }
  )
}
```